Using a 24 bit BMP with CTabCtrl
I am trying:
m_imgList.Create(32, 32, ILC_COLOR24 | ILC_MASK, 4, 4);

CBitmap bmp;
bmp.LoadBitmap(IDB_BMP_DATABASE_REPORT_VIEWER);
theApp.SetBitmapBackgroundAsMenuColour(bmp);

m_imgList.Add(&bmp, RGB(47, 47, 47));  // Replace with the correct transparent color

m_tabPreview.SetImageList(&m_imgList);
m_tabPreview.SetItemSize(CSize(0, 34));

I am almost there, but look:

It seems that the tab with focus does not necessarily have the right background colour for the icon.
I am confused.

Based on the suggestions, I have tried using a 32 bit PNG file instead:
// Create the image list and load the bitmap
m_imgList.Create(32, 32, ILC_COLOR32, 4, 4);

CPngImage png;
png.Load(IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR, AfxGetResourceHandle());
m_imgList.Add(static_cast<HICON>(png.Detach()));

m_tabPreview.SetImageList(&m_imgList);
m_tabPreview.SetItemSize(CSize(0, 34));

But I am not seeing any icons now.

You'll need to add an alpha channel and store it as a 32bpp image (and hope that the alpha channel doesn't get lost on load).

@IInspectable This works actually: m_imgList.Add(&bmp, GetSysColor(COLOR_MENU));.

That overload is used to fake transparency (by constructing a binary mask). It does not provide real, per-pixel alpha transparency. For that, you need a source image with an alpha channel. Try using a PNG icon and the int Add(HICON) overload. The image list needs to be created with the ILC_COLOR32 flag only.

@IInspectable I get that. Either I stick with 24 bit and fake transparency or 32 bit with proper transparency.  I see no official documentation stating what images the CTabCtrl will actually support. I might investigate the 32 bit route. But what I have is working fine.

@IInspectable I don't know how to get a HICON from a CPngImage: CPngImage png; png.Load(IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR, AfxGetResourceHandle()); m_imgList.Add((HICON)png);

It's working fine until the common controls library decides to use a different color for its tab control background, or the color value of COLOR_MENU changes. Using images with a dedicated alpha channel is the only sustainable solution. You can infer that the image list supports 32bpp images as it supports the ILC_COLOR32 flag.

@IInspectable I tried:  CPngImage png;  png.Load(IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR, AfxGetResourceHandle());  m_imgList.Add(static_cast<HICON>(png.Detach())); but my icons are not showing on the tab bar.

You have to create an actual .ico file from the PNG, using an offline icon editor tool (or a hex editor; the image format isn't exactly complex). I don't think you can (easily) convert a PNG image to an HICON at run time.

@IInspectable See my answer - I have it working.

This works:
// Create the image list and load the bitmap
m_imgList.Create(32, 32, ILC_COLOR32, 4, 4);

CPngImage png;
png.Load(IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR, AfxGetResourceHandle());

CBitmap bmp;
bmp.Attach(png.Detach());
m_imgList.Add(&bmp, nullptr);


